# null file when posting with WebRequest

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-framework-version

I need to post a file using WebRequest from an older .NET 3.5 app but the endpoint always got the file null

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("/api/app/savefile/")]
      public async Task<IActionResult> Salavef(IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
                  return BadRequest('No file');
..............
```

C# NET3.5 code:

```
        var uri = "https://localhost:44305/api/app/savefile"; 
        var filePath = @"d:\data.dat";
        var fileParameterName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        var contentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";

            string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
            byte[] boundaryBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newLine + "--" + boundary + newLine);
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);

            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {

                requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);

                string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"{2}Content-Type: {3}{2}{2}";
                string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, fileParameterName, filePath, newLine, contentType);
                byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
                requestStream.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
                    Int32 bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {

                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    }

                }

                byte[] trailer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newLine + "--" + boundary + "--" + newLine);
                requestStream.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);

            }

            System.Net.WebResponse response = null;

            try
            {

                response = request.GetResponse();

                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {

                    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {

                        var responseText = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                      
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException exception)
            {

                response = exception.Response;

                if (response != null)
                {

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {

                        var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            
                    }

                    response.Close();

                }

            }
            finally
            {

                request = null;

            }
```

got the code form [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)